# GRUB post-installation fails

Tags: apt, grub2, dpkg

Was going to actually ask a question, but I believe I already found the answer, so I'm posting here my problem and the solution I've found.

So the problem was this: `apt` fails for any command with the following error message.

```
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
   ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` will reveal that this is due to a syntax error in GRUB's post-installation script (`/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.postinst`):

```
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.10) ...
>>  /var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.postinst: line 703: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'  <<
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
```

Looking at the script it's clear that a semicolon is missing at line 699 before `then`:

```
       ...
    if dpkg --compare-versions "$2" lt-nl 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.10; then
       ...                                                       ^
```

Manually adding the semicolon and re-running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` fixed the issue for me.

Sidenote: my system is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Please add the solution to an answer, rather than posting it in the question.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has submitted an official Launchpad bug = https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1692235

Comment: Thanks, I tried googling for it, but couldn't find it.